# php mysqli query after json_encode gives error

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have 2 php arrays which I am encoding into json with `json_encode` and `$mysqli->real_escape_string`. Now, the output of these two arrays after json_encode is:

```
{\"arg1\":\"char*\",\"arg2\":\"char*\"}{\"arg1\":\"abc\",\"arg2\":\"bca\"}
```

Then, I am inserting this into mysql with a query. But I am getting the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\"arg1\":\"char*\",\"arg2\":\"char*\"}, {\"arg1\":\"abc\",\"arg2\":\"bca\"})' at line 1
```

What is the way I put this json into mysql?

Mysql query

```
"UPDATE test_info SET java_auto_frame=$frame_auto, java_manual_frame=$frame_manual, java_testcase=$testcases, param_types=$param_types, param_examples=$param_examples WHERE qid=$qid"
```

where, $param_types is the first json encoded array and $param_examples is the second one.

Comment: Where is your SQL query?

Comment: Obviously your `json` needs to be escaped decently if you are going to just paste it into a query like that...

Comment: You need to escape your input data http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). You might think it's unrelated, but this is exactly the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write your query like this

```
"UPDATE test_info SET java_auto_frame='$frame_auto', java_manual_frame='$frame_manual', java_testcase='$testcases', param_types='$param_types', param_examples='$param_examples' WHERE qid='$qid'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use prepared statement of PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).
Something like this:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;","root","");
$sql = "UPDATE test_info SET java_auto_frame=:frame_auto, java_manual_frame=:frame_manual, java_testcase=:testcases, param_types=:param_types, param_examples=:param_examples WHERE qid=:qid";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array(
    'frame_auto' => $frame_auto,
    'frame_manual' => $frame_manual,
    'testcases' => $testcases,
    'param_types' => $param_types,
    'param_examples' => $param_examples,
    'qid' => $qid
));
```

Comment: While PDO is an alternative solution, OP is asking about MySQLi implementation.